# Difference in cumulative sum based on specified values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing one column (depth, z) in which I am trying to find the difference in the accumulative depth values based on regular depth values. I would like to create a new dataframe with 3 columns: the criteria value, its respective cumulative depth value, and the third column with difference between consecutive cumulative depths, so for example:

```
z1<-c(1.2, 1.5, 0.8, 0.7, 1.6, 1.9, 1.1, 0.6, 1.3, 1.0)
z<-data.frame(z1)
crit1<-c(0.5,1,1.5,2)

# A loop comes to mind, 

for(i in c(0.5,1,1.5,2)){
print( sum(subset(z1,z1<=i)))
}                               # But I get an error, because I cannot use integers

Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Attempting with `cumsum`

```
 cumsum(z1)[seq(0.5,2,by=0.5)] # Which doesn't work either
```

I would like to get a table like this:

```
Crit     Cumulative      Difference
  0.5        0                0
  1          3.1              3.1
  1.5        8.2              5.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `for` loop here , you should use `sapply` since you store the result.

```
y <- sapply(crit1,function(x)sum(z1[z1<=x]))
d <- c(0,diff(y))

data.frame(Crit =  crit1,  Cumulative  =y,    Difference=d)

#   Crit Cumulative Difference
# 1  0.5        0.0        0.0
# 2  1.0        3.1        3.1
# 3  1.5        8.2        5.1
# 4  2.0       11.7        3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
 Difference <- setNames(c(0,tapply(z1,cut(z1, breaks=crit1,labels=F),FUN=sum)),NULL)
 data.frame(Crit=crit1, Cumulative=cumsum(Difference), Difference)
#    Crit Cumulative Difference
#1  0.5        0.0        0.0
#2  1.0        3.1        3.1
#3  1.5        8.2        5.1
#4  2.0       11.7        3.5
```